# How do I automatically push leads from Facebook Leads Center to my personal CRM via webhook or something else?

Tags: python, facebook, webhooks

I have a custom CRM which can accept leads on REST API. What should I do to get FB leads. Are Web-hooks the right way so leads come up as and when it is created.

Can someone share the right steps. FB documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, webhooks are the way to go, when you want to get updates send to your system automatically. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-leadgen/